# Mixed Parcelable data types in ArrayList as extras

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I have a "playlist" that is of type "ArrayList". When going through this list in my code I can easily check to see if it is instanceof Song, Album, Artist, Genre and cast to the correct type. All of the types implement Parcelable in android so they can be sent from activity to activity, but I am having an issue in trying to send the "playlist" through a broadcast receiver. Essentially once a song is over it will move on to the next item. That item could be an album or artist or whatever and my app knows how to handle it, but I need to broadcast that list to my MainActivity so I can show the playlist to the user on a button click. The problem is they are mixed types so I cant just say...

```
private BroadcastReceiver playlistUpdated = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<NOT SURE WHAT TO SAY HERE> tempList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(MusicService.PLAY_LIST_EXTRA);
    //... do more processing to add them to the base activity playlist and show
  }
};
```

I tried doing "ArrayList..." but it throws an error saying wrong data type. If I do "ArrayList..." how do I go about getting them back to normal objects once I have them?
The extra that is being passed will be an ArrayList that can contain Song, Album, Artist, or Genre. I am sure there is a way to do this, I just can't seem to figure it out. I am more than happy to show code that makes the list and processes the list in the MusicService if it is needed. Thank you.

UDPATE. Here is the code I am using for the items and the list...

Song..

```
public class Song implements Parcelable {
  private long id;
  private String title;
  private String artist;
  private String album;
  private String albumArtURI;

  public Song(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readLong();
    this.title = in.readString();
    ...
  }
  //rest of class... getters setters, writeToParcel, and the CREATOR
}
```

The album, artist, and genre are pretty much the exact same just with maybe different keys like album will have numSongs.

then creating the "playlist" array in my MusicService...

```
private ArrayList<Object> playlist = new ArrayList<>();
...
public void setPlayConfinedTo(Album album) {
  this.album = album;
  playlist.addAll(getSongsFromAlbum(album.getId());
}

public void setPlayConfinedTo(Album album, Artist artist) {
  this.artist = artist;
  this.album = album;
  playlist.addAll(getSongsFromAlbum(album.getId());
  ArrayList<Album> remainingAlbums = getAlbumsFromArtistWithoutAlbum(artist.getId(), album.getId());
  if(remainingAlbums.size() > 0) {
    playlist.addAll(remainingAlbums);
  }
}
```

The code for getSongsFromAlbum or getAlbumsFromArtistWithoutAlbum is just returning ArrayList or ArrayList. It uses ContentResolver to query the MediaStore.Audio. for the media in the db. Like so...

```
public ArrayList<Song> getSongsFromAlbum(long ID) {
  ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
  ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
  Cursor cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);
  ...loop through and get songs, create Song object add it to songs array;
  return songs;
}
```

So in the end I have an ArrayList that can have Album, Artist, Song, or Genre in it as an Object.

Comment: So this ArrayList is a list of different objects? Can you show how you are constructing the list?

Comment: You could make an interface called `Playable` which each of `Song`, `Album`, `Artist`, `Genre` would implement. Then you would use `ArrayList<Playable>`. The `Playable` interface could have methods such as `getName()` and `play()`, etc.

Comment: @remedy. I updated the code with the code used to get/save the ArrayList.

Comment: @Jason That is an interesting idea. I think I like it. I might give that a go. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't dealt with this in awhile but I don't think Jason's idea would work. I would write the size of the list and then each object. When you read it back, get the size and create another List and add each parcelable object into your new list.